# How to make a POST request in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make a POST request using Python
here is my POST request:

```
POST http://services.data.shom.fr/sos/client
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "request": "GetObservation",
  "service": "SOS",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "procedure": [
    "http://shom.fr/maregraphie/procedure/3"
  ],
  "offering": [
    "http://shom.fr/maregraphie/offering/3"
  ],
  "observedProperty": [
    "http://shom.fr/maregraphie/observedProperty/WaterHeight/4"
  ],
  "featureOfInterest": [
    "http://shom.fr/maregraphie/featureOfInterest/5"
  ],
  "temporalFilter": [
    {
      "during": {
        "ref": "om:phenomenonTime",
        "value": [
          "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",
          "2014-12-31T00:00:00Z"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and Here is my Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

import requests
import json


url = 'http://services.data.shom.fr/sos/client'
payload = {
  'request': 'GetObservation',
  'service': 'SOS',
  'version': '2.0.0',
  'procedure': [
    'http://shom.fr/maregraphie/procedure/3'
  ],
  'offering': [
    'http://shom.fr/maregraphie/offering/3'
  ],
  'observedProperty': [
    'http://shom.fr/maregraphie/observedProperty/WaterHeight/4'
  ],
  'featureOfInterest': [
    'http://shom.fr/maregraphie/featureOfInterest/5'
  ],
  'temporalFilter': [
    {
      'during': {
        'ref': 'om:phenomenonTime',
        'value': [
          '2014-01-01T00:00:00Z',
          '2014-12-31T00:00:00Z'
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url,data = payload, headers=headers)
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write(r.text)
f.close()
```

I get a syntax error, I understand that my syntax for my payload variable is not the right one but I can't figure it out. Any ideas ?

Comment: `requests.post(url,data = json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)`

Comment: What you have posted has no ``SyntaxError``(s) just *many* [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) issues.

Comment: FYI, next time please post the exception traceback too, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, it works ! 
here is the final python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

import requests
import json

# Server URL's
url = 'http://services.data.shom.fr/sos/client'
#
payload = {
    'request': 'GetObservation',
    'service': 'SOS',
    'version': '2.0.0',
    'procedure': ['http://shom.fr/maregraphie/procedure/3'],
    'offering': ['http://shom.fr/maregraphie/offering/3'],
    'observedProperty': ['http://shom.fr/maregraphie/observedProperty/WaterHeight/4'],
    'featureOfInterest': ['http://shom.fr/maregraphie/featureOfInterest/5'],
    'temporalFilter': [{'during': {'ref': 'om:phenomenonTime','value': ['2014-01-01T00:00:00Z','2014-12-31T00:00:00Z']}}]
}
#Header for the POST request
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

#Request
r = requests.post(url,data = json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
#Write response in a text file
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write(r.text)
f.close()
```